# Not Mapped Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am developing an application in `grails` and using `HQL` queries.

```
Query=A.findAll("from A b where  b.boom=:boom
```

I am getting this error.

```
not mapped:nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
```

I have tried to use full  package name but it gives another error:`could not locate named parameter[boom].`

Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def result = A.findAll("from A a where a.boom=:boom", [boom: 'boom value'])
```

(See [the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def resultList = A.findAll("from A as b where b.boom = :boom", [boom: yourBoom])
```

If this dosn't work, provide some more code of your domain `A` and according `controller`/`service` code.

You should use more meaningful variable names - why do you name your `A` class `b` in the query.

Comment: Sorry , i ddint paste the full code , infact i have done same as above,

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code. What is the value of your _:boom_ in the _findAll()_ method? Looks like the parameter _boom_ is not set.